# How to use confidential production keys on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, key

I am implementing a payment gateway on my personal website. I am using a web builder software with adequate knowledge of HTML and googled knowledge of javascript on a need basis.

So, my payment gateway tells me to put this code on my website:

```
<input id="Key1" name="Key1" type="hidden" value="llsejjtoewe4">
<input id="Key2" name="Key2" type="hidden" value="628347832752">
```

*(dummy values pasted here)*

But then it says that these should be kept **highly confidential.**

When I uploaded my website, I can see that the visitors can see the source of the page which clearly shows these keys and the `<script>` code that follows. Is it how it's supposed to be?

Note that the code also contains encryption methods down the road so the transmission of data is okay.

Answer (score 1):

The keys you use in JavaScript and HTML can't be effectively hidden and mentioning these keys in the code is a security threat.

You should use a back-end server because usually all secret information is stored in a `.env` file

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using Front-End technology, you can't stop user from knowing the source code. Best you can do (only using Front-End technology) is creating an element (or elements) with JavaScript (or any other programming language such as TypeScript). Then, you obfuscate that code.
Except that, you should use some Back-End technology.

[More info](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2016/02/15/securing-api-keys-in-a-javascript-single-page-app/)

Sorry for my bad grammar.